# CS50x pset3 (Why doesn't my program pass Check50?)

Tags: c, computer-science, cs50

I completed my Problem Set 3 helpers.c program and it works perfectly up to a total of 10 of haystack but stops working when I press Control-D with less than 10 in haystack. Instead the program skips a line and I can freely write like in a not pad. Since, it can not pass 3 or 4 in haystacks, my program can't pass Check50. Does anybody have a solution to this problem?

In case you need my code, here it is:

```
bool search(int value, int values[], int n)
{
     if(value < 0)
     {
         return false;
     }

     for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
     {
         if (value == values[i])
         {
            return true;
         }
     }

     return false;

 }

 /**
 * Sorts array of n values.
 */
 void sort(int values[], int n)
 {
     bool tf;
     do
     {
         tf = false;
         for(int i=0; i < n-1; i++)
         {
             if(values[i] > values[i+1])
             {
                 int temp = values[i];
                 values[i] = values[i+1];
                 values[i+1] = temp;
                 tf = true;
             }
         }
     }
     while(tf == false);
     return;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sorting algorithm is flawed. It just takes one round of the whole array and arranges it partially in order but not fully.

You can use bubble sort (refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort or the lecture of cs50) of which I cannot provide code as it is against the honour code of the course.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. By making a second "j" loop, would I be on the right track?

Comment: Yes, kind of and do remove that do while loop that's not of any use.

Comment: @SamuelHanssen You can also use an outer-while with descending top-limit and inner-for, along with swap-detection, a very common algorithm for [bubble-sort](http://pastebin.com/sheqN11j).